# Android dynamic radio buttons get value

Tags: android, radio-button

I am developing a contest ( multiple choice type ) in android with server database.
Had many questions with multiple choice answers ( 4 per each ). Creating the questions by the following code

```
try {
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(questions).nextValue();



        TextView active=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.active);
        active.setText(description);
        active.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.questions_lay);

          for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
              JSONObject question = array.getJSONObject(i);
              Integer id=question.getInt("id");


              TextView title = new TextView(this);
               title.setText(question.getString("ques"));
               title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
               ll.addView(title);

               final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[4];
               RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
               rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

               rb[0] = new RadioButton(this);
               rb[0].setText(question.getString("opt_a"));

               rb[1] = new RadioButton(this);
               rb[1].setText(question.getString("opt_b"));
               rb[2] = new RadioButton(this);
               rb[2].setText(question.getString("opt_c"));
               rb[3] = new RadioButton(this);
               rb[3].setText(question.getString("opt_d"));

               rg.addView(rb[0]);
               rg.addView(rb[1]);
               rg.addView(rb[2]);
               rg.addView(rb[3]);

               ll.addView(rg);
          }

          ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            overLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // handle JSON parsing exceptions...
        Toast.makeText(ContestActivity.this,"Error Occured ! Please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cd.goHome(ContestActivity.this);
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now on a button click I need to send the answers to the server. I am new to android and my doubts are

1. IS there any option to set the Value to each radio button ?
2. How to get the selected radiobutton in a button click ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to `setTag("some value")` to radio button? and on button click call `getTag()`.. i never used it with radio button, but I hope it will work. tell me if its not

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried that. But On a button click, how to get all the radiobutton checked values ?

Comment: try like this 'RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) v;          String result = radio.getTag().toString();'

Comment: thanks.. how to get all the radiogroups in an array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok first create a button in your layout :

1) your Question goes here ?

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

  Click me Button

This is your layout:

now if you want to set some values to radio button then set it via setTag or setId and then in code :

```
final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[4];
rb[1].setTag("some value");
rb[1].setId(1);
int arrayQID[] = new Int[array.length()];
```

and then on click listener of your button

```
int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(selectedId);
String value = (String)radioButton.getTag();
int value2 = radioButton.getId();

    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
          JSONObject question = array.getJSONObject(i);
          Integer id=question.getInt("id");


          TextView title = new TextView(this);
           title.setText(question.getString("ques"));
           title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
           ll.addView(title);

           final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[4];
           RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
           rg.setId(qid); // i suggest set your question id here instead of loop count
           rg.setTag("some value"); // Some value
           arrayQID[i] = qid
           rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

           rb[0] = new RadioButton(this);
           rb[0].setText(question.getString("opt_a"));
           rb.[0].setId(id); //id should be unique (not the same for each radioGroup [1]
           rb.[0].setTag("qid"+"opt_a");
           rb[1] = new RadioButton(this);
           rb[1].setText(question.getString("opt_b"));
           rb[2] = new RadioButton(this);
           rb[2].setText(question.getString("opt_c"));
           rb[3] = new RadioButton(this);
           rb[3].setText(question.getString("opt_d"));

           rg.addView(rb[0]);
           rg.addView(rb[1]);
           rg.addView(rb[2]);
           rg.addView(rb[3]);

           ll.addView(rg);
      }
```

[1] here you can built your logic by combining the question id and option id ie (qid + opt_a_id) = id and decode it where gid = radioButtonid - opt_a_id something like this in shot you make an id which is unique and can be decoded so that you know that this radioButton belongs to this question
Similarly you can use tags to get the view object with the help of findViewWithTag("qid"+"opt_a");
you can do this

```
RadioButton rb = layout.findViewWithTag("qid"+"opt_a");
```

and to get all question and answer you can set foreach loop:

```
for(int qid : arrayQID) {
    RadioButton rb = layout.findViewWithTag("qid"+"opt_a"); // OR
    RadioButton rb = layout.findViewById(id); // Unique id ie (qid + opt_a_Id)
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks. But I got more than 1 questions. How to get the radiogroup in a loop and get the values ?

Comment: are you trying to display more then one questions in one screen??

Comment: then i suggest you to use expandablelistview or see my edited answer for the second option